# Tomcat 7.0 throws error when starting

Tags: java, tomcat, localhost, startup, ping

I'm trying to start a Tomcat 7.0 server. During startup, this error is thrown:

```
October 31, 2013 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: create
        at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
```

How do I start the server properly?

Comment: On what type hardware is this?

Comment: window7 .   I'm a bit puzzled that why the file windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts can't be resolved .  the setting :127.0.0.1 localhost   doesn't work.

Comment: what does ipconfig /all report?

Answer (score 1):

You original question mentioned that you can not ping localhost.  If this is this case then Tomcat will not be able to start on localhost either.

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/34783/what-would-cause-ping-localhost-to-fail

Comment: windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts the file i have edited,but  the file don't work,it can't be resolved . So puzzled.

Comment: If networking is not working in Windows you cannot access any network service including to bind a port on localhost.